# PHP Learning OOP and Ajax, and an OOP error

Tags: php, ajax

There's three things I'd like to discuss:
 1. Where's a good resource to learn Ajax? I've seen this site, but it doesn't contain much information:
http://www.php-learn-it.com/tutorials/starting_with_php_and_ajax.html

 2. Wheres a good resource to learn OOP? I've done all steps on this site:
http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/ but it's from 2007.

***3 solved! ***
 3. And a question about the killerphp tutorial;
 Why do I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\class_lib.php on line 11
```

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\class_lib.php on line 11

**with this code(index.php):**

```
<?php
$william = new person("William N");

echo "<p>name: ". $william->get_name()."</p>";
```

?>

**and this in class_lib.php:**

```
class person {
var $name;

function __construct($persons_name)
{
    $this->name = $persons_name;
}
public function get_name()
{
     return $this->$name;
}
```

}

Comment: Immediately discard your PHP tutorial if it is telling you to declare your class properties with `var`. You should be using `public`, `protected`, `private` for you property declarations.  The best documentation is usually php.net.  Read through the documentaion on OOP here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php this would be better (and likely more current) than many any tutorial you could find.

Comment: As I wrote this guide is from 2007, that's why I'm asking for other learning resources. I don't need 300 pages in pdf, I have good knowledge about procedural PHP, I just need somewhere to start with OO PHP

Comment: Even better reason to just look at the PHP.net documentation on objects/classes.  You already have familiarity with the language, so you just need the syntax of classes/objects.  Once you have that down, then might look at a more in depth text around proper usage (OOP patterns, and such).  This is a decent text for that purpose http://www.amazon.com/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Matt-Zandstra/dp/1590599098

Answer (score 3):

```
return $this->$name;
```

should be:

```
return $this->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
class person {
   protected $name;

  public function __construct($persons_name)
  {
        $this->name = $persons_name;
  }
   public function get_name()
   {
        return $this->name;
   }
```

Are you using PHP 5?
You should not use var anymore if so.

Comment: I'm new to OOP and well, the reason I ask for other OOP learning resources is because this guide is written 6 years ago. $this->name fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your 3rd question is answered already, as far as 2nd one goes I haven't read the book, but php.net as always gives you all the basics and even more with the examples that follow on almost each and every page. :)